# C file does not work in my own R package?

Tags: r

I built my own package in R and created all my functions. Everything worked very well. Then, I want to include a `.C` files into my package.

I follow the structure in this link [compiled code](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html). Once I done that, my package stop working and cannot use it anymore.

I tried to fix it more than one time but nothing is happen. Then, I built another package and load my functions inside it (I was save a copy of my files).

Now I would like to start again but do not want to lose my function again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write your files first and make sure that they are work! Then build you package following the structures [here](http://web.mit.edu/insong/www/pdf/rpackage_instructions.pdf).

Follow the structures step by step and you will be fine. Your package will set `src` file for you and all your other files.